# Simple maths in Objective-C producing unexpected results

Tags: objective-c, math

I'm doing the following in Objective-C and expecting 180 as the output but I'm getting 150. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

`(360 / 100) * 50`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're (accidentally) using [integer division](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#2.5).  `360 / 100` is returning `3`, then `3 * 50` is of course `150`.  To obtain a floating point result, try casting `360` or `100` to a float first, or just use a literal float - i.e., `360.0 / 100` or `360 / 100.0` or even `360.0 / 100.0`.

Or, as @KennyTM pointed out in a comment, you can reorder the statement such as `360 * 50 / 100` -- this is particularly useful if a floating-point number is unacceptable for any reason.